# jquery validation of textarea integrated with ckeditor

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-validate, ckeditor

I have a `text-area`

```
<td><textarea id="event-body" name="body">
<p class="error"></p>
```

That is integrated with CKEDITOR

```
CKEDITOR.replace("event-body")
```

And jquery validate [plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/validation). And  the code is like this

```
$('#event').validate({
    rules:{
        name:{
            required: true
        },  
    },
    messages:{
        body:{
            required: "event body is required"
        }
    },
    errorPlacement: function(error, element){
        $(element).each(function (){
            $(this).parent('td').find('p.error').html(error);
        })
    });
```

The code works just fine but when I type into my `textarea` element, I still get the error message until I click it twice. i.e. I have to submit my page twice so that I don't error message even if `textarea` is not empty.

Isn't there a way to validate it smoothly(without having to click it twice).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Take a look [here](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.editor.html#updateElement)

Basically you need to call

```
CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.updateElement();
```

before running validation.

Just replace `editor1` with the name of your textarea.

Then call

```
$(myformelement).validate();
```

**EDIT**

```
$("#my-form-submit-button").click(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     CKEDITOR.instances.event-body.updateElement();
     $('#event').validate({
          ...options as above..
     });o
})
```

Comment: what where should I run this code. Have a look at my validate function

Comment: Not working for me. I have made that field required but form submits without filling it.

Answer (score 4):

Put this in submit button mousedown() event:

```
$("#submit").mousedown(function(){
  for (var i in CKEDITOR.instances){
    CKEDITOR.instances[i].updateElement();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

jQuery validator only validate input fields that are visible but CKEDITOR makes the textarea hidden preventing it from being validated.

Comment: Is this verified? I tried all of the above suggestions and still did not manage to get it working. I know my validation code was fine because it worked great without CKEditor. I wrote manual validation, so I know that the textareas were getting updated when I called the CKEDITOR.instance.updateElement() method. But when I submit my form with jQuery validate and CKEditor, validation doesn't trigger at all.

Comment: The textarea you are seeing in CKEDITOR is not the same textarea you define in your HTML. CKEDITOR replaces it with its own editor thus hiding the normal textarea you define.

Answer (score 2):

I've combined your sugestions and make this little cheat that works with no problem.

My code:

```
<form id="create-message-form-3" class="form-horizontal" role="form" accept-charset="utf-8">
                <div class="title"><h1>Add Content:</h1></div>
                <div class="col col-12">
                  <textarea class="form-control ckeditor" name="templateeditor" id="templateeditor" rows="6"></textarea>
                  <p class="error"></p>
                </div>



                <div class="text-center">
                    <a class="btn btn-success pull-left" href="create-message-2.php">Back</a>
                    <input class="btn btn-default" type="button" value="Save">
                    <input id="submit-templateeditor" class="btn btn-success pull-right" type="submit" value="Next Step">
                </div>
             </form>
```

On my .css file, I forced my  to be like this:

```
textarea.ckeditor {
visibility: visible !important;
display: block !important;
height: 0px !important;
border: none !important;
resize:none;
overflow: hidden; }
```

And my .js validation is the normal format:

```
    $("#submit-templateeditor").click(function(){
     CKEDITOR.instances.templateeditor.updateElement();
     $("#create-message-form-3").validate({
        rules: {
            templateeditor: "required"
        },
        messages: {
            templateeditor: "Please add some code before continue"
        },
        errorPlacement: function(error, element){
            $(element).each(function (){
                $(this).parent('div').find('p.error').html(error);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! This question is 3 years old, while it is good that you found a solution to the problem, the question had already been solved, bring this post back to activity serves nothing. In the future please refrain from bringing back long dead posts :)

Answer (score 1):

Use this in your javascript where you are validating your form. It will update your ckeditor and will assign ckeditor's value to your textarea to which you integrate it.

It should run before form is submitted:

```
CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.updateElement();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are attaching it like

```
$("#Detail").ckeditor(config);
```

than you will need to use something like this

```
var editor = $('#Detail').ckeditorGet();
editor.updateElement();
```

I use this example function to submit my form in this case

```
function SubmitEvent(){
    var editor = $('#Detail').ckeditorGet();
    editor.updateElement();
    if($("#EventForm").valid()) {
        $('#EventForm').submit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer to update each instance on blur event, so you don't need to change anything on your submit function! :)

```
$('#myInstance').ckeditor({toolbar:'MyToolbar'});
CKEDITOR.instances.myInstance.on('blur', function( e ){
    CKEDITOR.instances.myInstance.updateElement();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery .validate() function provides "onsubmit" option to perform custom action before validation.
    By default it is set to true.
        I have used it in my project and it works very well.

```
        $(".selector").validate({
          onsubmit: function(){
                    CKEditorUpdate();
                    return true;
                },
                rules:{
                    title:{required:true},
                    content:{required:true}
                },
                messages:{
                    title:{required:"Please enter a title"},
                    content:{required:"Please enter some content"}
                },
                submitHandler : function(form){
        });

    function CKEditorUpdate() {
        for (instance in CKEDITOR.instances)
            CKEDITOR.instances[instance].updateElement();
    }
```

This is a cleaner and much easier to understand approach.
Refer http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate#onsubmit

Answer (score 0):

IF your using SPRY, This is what worked for me....

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {

    CKEDITOR.instances["editor1"].on("instanceReady", function () {

        //set keyup event
        this.document.on("keyup", function () { CKEDITOR.instances["editor1"].updateElement(); });
        //and paste event
        this.document.on("paste", function () { CKEDITOR.instances["editor1"].updateElement(); });
        //and cut event
        this.document.on("cut", function () { CKEDITOR.instances["editor1"].updateElement(); });

    });

    CKEDITOR.instances["editor2"].on("instanceReady", function () {

        //set keyup event
        this.document.on("keyup", function () { CKEDITOR.instances["editor2"].updateElement(); });
        //and paste event
        this.document.on("paste", function () { CKEDITOR.instances["editor2"].updateElement(); });
        //and cut event
        this.document.on("cut", function () { CKEDITOR.instances["editor2"].updateElement(); });

    });

    CKEDITOR.instances["editor3"].on("instanceReady", function () {

        //set keyup event
        this.document.on("keyup", function () { CKEDITOR.instances["editor3"].updateElement(); });
        //and paste event
        this.document.on("paste", function () { CKEDITOR.instances["editor3"].updateElement(); });
        //and cut event
        this.document.on("cut", function () { CKEDITOR.instances["editor3"].updateElement(); });

    });

});
</script>
```