# ck editor - cant catch submit;

Tags: jquery, forms, post, ckeditor

I am trying to catch a form submission with jquery that is submitted via pressing save in ck editor.

My javascript code is

```
$(function() {
    var config = {
        skin : 'office2003',
        toolbar :[
            ['Save','Preview'],
            ['Cut','Copy','Paste','PasteText','PasteFromWord','-','Print'],
            ['Undo','Redo','-','Find','Replace','-','SelectAll','RemoveFormat'],
            ['NumberedList','BulletedList','-','Outdent','Indent','Blockquote'],
            ['JustifyLeft','JustifyCenter','JustifyRight','JustifyBlock'],
            ['Link','Unlink'],
            ['Image','Table','HorizontalRule','SpecialChar','Iframe'],
            ['Format','Font','FontSize'],
            ['TextColor','BGColor', 'Bold','Italic','Underline','Strike','-','Subscript','Superscript']
        ]
    };
    $('#cont').ckeditor(config);

    $('form').submit(function() {
        var form = $(this);
        var name = form.children('#name').val();
        var desc = form.children('#desc').val();
        var cont = form.children('#cont').val();
        var id = form.children('#id').val();

        $.ajax({
            url: basePath + 'admin/ajax/pages/edit',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                name: name,
                desc: desc,
                cont: cont,
                id:   id
            },
            success: function(data) {
                if (data.response)
                    $('#ajaxSuccess').show('fast').delay(10000).hide('fast');
                else
                    $('#ajaxError').show('fast').delay(10000).hide('fast');

            },
            error: function(data) {
                $('#ajaxError').show('fast').delay(10000).hide('fast');
            }
        });
        return false;

    });

});
```

But for some reason the submit handler doesn't even seem to be called (tested via `alert('called');` as first line), instead the form is submitted normally.

What am I doing wrong?

---

Based on the answer below I have updated my code to be

```
$(function() {
    var saveCmd = {
        modes : { wysiwyg:1, source:1 },
        exec : function( editor ){
            jQuery($form = editor.element.$.form).submit();
        }
    };

    var pluginName = 'safesave';

    // Register a plugin named "save".
    CKEDITOR.plugins.add(pluginName, {
        init : function( editor ){
            var command = editor.addCommand( pluginName, saveCmd );
            command.modes = { wysiwyg : !!( editor.element.$.form ) };

            editor.ui.addButton( 'SafeSave',{
                label     : editor.lang.save,
                command   : pluginName,
                className : 'cke_button_save'
            });
        }
    });


    var config = {
        skin : 'office2003',
        toolbar :[
            ['SafeSave','Preview'],
    ...
```

But now I have no save button, whats up?

Comment: `$('form').submit(function() { alert('hello'); })` to check if submit is being called or not.

Comment: @experimentX - CKEditor submits using a javascript `form.submit()` call which is impossible to catch with jQuery or in any other way.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5126565/jquery-validation-of-textarea-integrated-with-ckeditor also might be helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, you can't.  You need a different save module.  I wrote this for this exact purpose:

```
(function(){
    var saveCmd = {
        modes : { wysiwyg:1, source:1 },
        exec : function( editor ){
            jQuery($form = editor.element.$.form).submit();
        }
    };

    var pluginName = 'safesave';

    // Register a plugin named "save".
    CKEDITOR.plugins.add(pluginName, {
        init : function( editor ){
            var command = editor.addCommand( pluginName, saveCmd );
            command.modes = { wysiwyg : !!( editor.element.$.form ) };

            editor.ui.addButton( 'SafeSave',{
                label     : editor.lang.save,
                command   : pluginName,
                className : 'cke_button_save'
            });
        }
    });
})();
```

Now just change your command from `save` to `SafeSave`.  Not sure why I called it `SafeSave`, maybe I was tired like I am now :)

Note that this depends on jQuery.  If you aren't using jQuery, change the `exec` function.

Comment: Sorry, the string in the toolbar should be `SafeSave`, not `safesave`.  Typo.

Comment: oh, and `extraPlugins : 'safesave'` in the `config` object.  Sorry, I haven't used this in a while :)  (and yes, that one should be lower case)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [beforeCommandExec](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.editor.html#event%3abeforeCommandExec) event & [cancel()](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.eventInfo.html#cancel) method:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.ckeditoriz').ckeditor(/* config */);

    $('.ckeditoriz').each(function () {
        var id = $(this).attr('id'),
            form = this.form;

        CKEDITOR.instances[id].on('beforeCommandExec', function (event) {
            if (event.data.name === 'save') {
                event.cancel();
                $(form).submit();
            }
        });

    });

    $('.ajaxForm').submit(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var $this = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            type: $this.attr('method'),
            url: $this.attr('action'),
            data: $this.serialize()
        });
    });

});
</script>

<form action="url" method="post" class="ajaxForm">
  <!-- Your textarea must have an ID! -->
  <textarea id="textarea1" name="textarea1" class="ckeditoriz"></textarea>
</form>
```

### Update:

This doesn't work in CKEditor versions **4.0**, **4.1**, **4.2**, however it works again since version **4.3**.

Since CKEditor version **4.2** you can use the [save](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-event-save) event with the [cancel()](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.eventInfo-method-cancel) method:

```
CKEDITOR.instances[id].on('save', function (event) {
    event.cancel();
    $(form).submit();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can catch the submit using the javascript pseudo-protocol:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function Save() {
        // called when the save button is pressed
    }
</script>
```

...

```
<form action="javascript:Save()">...</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to update a element onchange ckeditor use this code:

```
for (var i in CKEDITOR.instances) {
    CKEDITOR.instances[i].on('change', function() { 
    CKEDITOR.instances[i].updateElement() });
}
```